# Why do I get an error in the MainWindow when trying to initialize a textbox in a UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I created a `UserControl` that contains a `textbox`. When I try to initialize the `textbox` in the constructor of the `UserControl`, with some text like this

```
public FileSelector()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    TB_FolderPath.Text = @"c:\tmp\Test\";
}
```

I get an error in the MainWindow.xaml

> Cannot create an instance of "FileSelector".

When I remove the row

```
TB_FolderPath.Text = @"c:\tmp\Test\";
```

I don't get the error, but of course an empty `textbox`.

Previously when I had the parts of the `UserControl` integrated in the `MainWindow`, there was also no problem.

I tried to create a simpler version of `MainWindow` using a `UserControl` to reproduce the problem, but in a simple case it works.

So, my questions.

- What can be the cause of the problem?
- How can I debug/analyze a problem like this systematically? I just get the this error in VisualStudio after building, without an explanation.
- How/Where can I initialize the controls in a `UserControl`. In general, is the `UserControl` the right place to initialize the controls or would the `MainWindow` be also a possibility? (Is this possible at all?)

Comment: Can you elaborate your problem? I tried creating a custom control with a text box in it, initialized it in ctor (as u did), then just dragged the control on main window and ran the program, it ran without any error. I'm using .net 4.0 client framework.

Comment: @AmarPalsapure As I wrote, I also tried to reproduce this with a simple example and there it worked, at the moment I have no more idea what info I should add.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In WPF, unlike WinForms, the controls are not initialized completely after InitializeComponent(). Hence the uninitialized/unloaded controls throw errors.

You need to write handler to capture the Loaded event of the control.

Read [Object Lifetime Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754221.aspx).

Get some more detailed info [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikehillberg/archive/2006/09/19/loadedvsinitialized.aspx).

Example (partially taken from OP's code):

```
public FileSelector()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    TB_FolderPath.Loaded += delegate { TB_FolderPath.Text = @"c:\tmp\Test\"; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to solve this problem (It does now fail at a later point, need to analyze), thanks for the links, need to read them to understand more what happens here.

Comment: Your answer did not fix my real problem (it fixed the one I described) but then my program failed at the real problem, but this is completely different, I will have to change my data model to fix that.